# Converting Summation into matrix form

Tags: matrices, summation

Would require some help on this

$\sum{r_i^2 * e_i^2}$

would it be equivalent to

$(re)^T(re)$. It does seem to be equivalent but i cannot seem to prove it.

Assuming r and e are both vectors.

Thanks!

Comment: If $r$ and $e$ are both vectors, what does $re$ mean?

Comment: @NickD r dot product e

Comment: Then what is $(re)^T$?

Comment: Hmmm. The transpose of the dot product of r and e

Comment: And how is that different from the dot product itself?

Comment: Coz $\sum{e_i^2}$ is equals to e.T * e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89462/discussion-between-nickd-and-aceminer).

Comment: Let $R={\rm Diag}(r),$ i.e. a diagonal matrix with the vector $r$ as the diagonal elements. Then your function can be written as $$f = (Re)^T(Re) = e^TR^TRe$$

Comment: @greg i would have accepted your answer if it was an answer but its a comment so i can only upvote the comment

Answer (score 0):

Just write it out componentwise for two dimensional vectors.

If $re$ is the dot product as you say in the comments it is not.  $\sum r_i^2*e_i^2=r_1^2e_1^2+r_2^2e_2^2$ while $re$ is a scalar $(re)=r_1e_1+r_2e_2$ and $(re)^T(re)$ is the square of this which includes a term $2r_1e_1r_2e_2$

If $(re)$ is a vector that is the componentwise product of $r$ and $e$ it is true.  Write it out for yourself.

Comment: So how do I express this summation in wuadaratic form?

Comment: I don't know the word wuadaratic.  When I put it into a famous search engine it changes it into quadratic.

Comment: Yes it was a typo i realized my mistake

Comment: I don't understand what "express a summation in quadratic form" means.Your summation is a product of squares.

Comment: Like if I were to compute this in matrices. How would the matrixes be represented

Comment: Your first expression is a fine way to express it.  I haven't seen a need for this, so I doubt there is an easier way.  Componentwise multiplication of vectors is rarely seen because it doesn't transform nicely when you change the basis.  Why do you need this?